# Prevent apk download from google play

Tags: android, google-play, android-security

Currently I want to prevent our apk download from google play by external websites eg: [APK downlader from googleplay](https://apk-dl.com). Is there any way to prevent it ?

Comment: Nope. 10 chars..

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Answer (score 1):

You can send a DMCA mail to that site (https://apk-dl.com/dmca) but as long as your apk is on google play (or any other place online) others will be able to download and redistribute.